# Toggle items from between choice widgets

Tags: php, jquery, widget

I'm using Symfony2.3.4 and jQuery, or at least trying to.

The thing is I have a form with two choice widgets(in each multiple=true and expanded=false) and two buttons. This form was generated with Doctrine's crud, so I'm currently getting familiar to the code it generated. After a while searching the web, a long while since I'm new to a lot about web programming, I managed to get a function to remove the selected options from one choice widget and append them to the other using the id of each widget:

```
//../custom_js.js
 function move_option_among_choices(id_from, id_to) {
     $('#' + id_to).append($('#' + id_from + ' option:selected'));
}
```

Here comes the problem:

1. I click an option from the first widget(id_from).
2. I press the button that executes the func above.
3. I see that the selected option is removed from the first widget and appears now in the second.
4. I submit the form...

only I can't do what I want to do with the moved options because they are not there.
when I try to access the second widget's options:

```
var_dump($form->get('selected_prof')->getConfig()->getOptions()['choices']);
```

I get an empty array although every time a press the button that executes the js func it moves the option from the first widget to the second.

It's like the function only moves the text, the actual component/option(idk how to call it) is internally still in the first widget.

Is there a way to fix this?

It doesn't matter if it's either a different way to access the options in the second widget or a different way of appending them to it.

Thanks.

```
{% extends 'AdminBundle:Default:administracion.html.twig' %}

{% block contenido -%}
<h1>Nuevo Comit&eacute; Acad&eacute;mico</h1>

{% if error %}
<div class="alert alert-error my_error">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                {{ error }}
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="row-fluid">      
<form class="form-horizontal sf_admin_form_area" 
action="{{ path('comiteacad_create') }}" 
      method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="icon-ok"></i> {{'Guardar' | trans}}</button>

        <a class="btn" href="{{ path('comiteacad') }}">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> {{'Cancelar' | trans }}</a>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Post your html layout

Comment: @Tomanow there it is, although I don't know if it'll do any good since all the heavy duty happens "inside" {{ form_widget(form) }}